# Android about stream api

Tags: android, hashmap, java-stream

I wanted to use stream api on my project [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) and [RetroLambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

**Code:**

```
Map<String, Object> liste = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> data : tumListe.entrySet()) {
    try{
        if (data.getValue() != null) {
            if(data.getValue() instanceof String){
                try {
                    liste.put(data.getKey(), new Gson().fromJson(((String) data.getValue()), new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType()));
                }catch (JsonIOException ignored){
                    continue;
                }catch (JsonParseException ignored){
                    continue;
                }
            }

            liste.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue());
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException | ClassCastException ignored) {}
}
```

How can I refactor this code to use streams e.g. `Stream.of()` method?

Answer (score 1):

`Stream.of` takes List/Iterator/Iterable so you can simply write `Stream.of(hashMap.entrySet())` or `Stream.of(hashMap)` and iterate over map entries with Stream API. Next, you can filter only non-null values `filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)` and perform operations in `forEach` method.

To skip unnecessary try/catch blocks use `Exceptional` class (LSA feature only).

Code:

```
Map<String, Object> liste = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(tumListe)
        .filter(data -> data.getValue() != null)
        .forEach(data -> Exceptional.of(() -> {
            if (data.getValue() instanceof String) {
                liste.put(data.getKey(), new Gson().fromJson((String) data.getValue()));
            } else {
                liste.put(data.getKey(), data.getValue());
            }
            return null; // irrelevant, for Exceptional result
        }));
```